# Clearing specific widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to have a function in python that clears the screen upon a button being pressed. I am aware of grid_remove but am unsure of how to use it. Also is there a way to clear everything from a specific function, ie both "hi" and "clear"?

```
from tkinter import *

class Movies:
    def __init__(self, master):
        hi = Label(text = "Hello")
        hi.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        clear = Button(text = "Click", command=self.clear)
        clear.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    def clear(self):
        hi.grid_remove()




root = Tk()
gui = Movies(root)
root.geometry("100x200+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clear"? Do you want to destroy the widgets and replace them with different widgets, or are you wanting to keep the widgets but remove the text that is displayed (ie: set the label to an empty string)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in `winfo_children` method if you're just wanting to toggle hiding / showing all of the widgets in whatever parent holds the widgets. Small example:

```
from tkinter import *

class Movies:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.state = 1

        for i in range(5):
            Label(self.master, text='Label %d' % i).grid(row=0, column=i)
        self.magic_btn = Button(self.master, text='Make the Magic!', 
            command=self.magic)
        self.magic_btn.grid(columnspan=5)

    def magic(self):

        self.state = not self.state
        for widget in self.master.winfo_children(): #iterate over all child widgets in the parent
            #Comment out to clear the button too, or leave to toggle widget states
            if widget != self.magic_btn: #or some other widget you want to stay shown
                if self.state:
                    widget.grid()
                else:
                    widget.grid_remove()
                print(self.state)


root = Tk()
gui = Movies(root)
root.mainloop()
```